# Providing a Sparql endpoint for CKAN metadata

Tags: rdf, sparql, ckan, linked-data, opendata

I'm using CKAN's [ckanext-dcat](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-dcat) extension to publish metadata as RDF/DCAT. And even though it allows to [list all the records](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-dcat#catalog-endpoint), it doesn't allow to query them.

I've also tried the [ckanext-sparql](https://github.com/georgepm/ckanext-sparql) extension, but it merely allows to query an arbitrary (external) Sparql endpoint, and not CKAN's metadata catalog.

So, my question is, **how to query CKAN's metadata using Sparql?** Do I need to manually dump all the catalog as RDF/DCAT and import it into an external server like [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way anyone's going to write a SPARQL engine on top of the CKAN database - the metadata will need transferring to a triple store.

ckanext-dcat is the best way to convert the records to RDF, and you're using that which is good.

So the only bit missing is bit to putting the RDF into the triple store. I've never done this, but imagine it is a one-liner - syntax depending on your triple store.

Comment: Could you advise me a triplestore to use with CKAN? Ideally, I would point it to the ``/catalog.rdf`` endpoint provided by ``ckanext-dcat`` and it would regularly harvest CKAN's metadata.

Comment: I have nothing more to offer